# How can I debug unmanaged interface which is used by managed client

Tags: debugging

How can I debug unmanaged interface which is used by managed client.

I have an interface named TestInterface which is built with unmanaged C++. Also have a client, client1, built in managed C# which uses the interface TestInterface. The break point in TestInterface is not hitting condition when I am attaching the client process.

How can I make it debuggable.

Answer (score 0):

If VS2010, set Project | Properties | Configuration Properties | Debugging | Debugger Type = Mixed. Same thing for other versions but possibly different path to get to Debugger Type.